# load ajax url on new page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image]i know this question is not asked well & iam sorry for that

given requirement is that url shoul be open in _blank page but i have design ajax url is it possible ajax url is open in new page? like regular url other wise i have to change lots of things here is the code

```
  function pdfPrint(start_date , end_date , view){

    var startDate = $('#setDate-'+start_date).val();
    var endDate = $('#setDate-'+end_date).val();       
    data = {
            "startDate":startDate,
            "endDate":endDate,
            "view":view,
            "systemid":system_id,
        };
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('download.pdf')}}",
        type: "get",
        'headers': {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        data:data,
    }).done(downloadFile);       
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$.ajax` - use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: thanx but i get http://127.0.0.1:8000/[object%20Object]

Comment: and url should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/download/pdf?startDate=30Oct21&endDate=30Oct21&view=hydrogen&systemid=1040000000338

Comment: then your server side template is not populating the Url correctly. Can't help fix your templates.

Answer (score 1):

this simple trick to open window and exec js code;

```
let js = `<script>
    function pdfPrint() {
        window.print();
    }
    
    // exec your function
    pdfPrint();</` + `script>`;

let win = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=400");
win.document.write(js);
```

Comment: script is doing something wrong

Comment: see image which i attached

Comment: follow this url https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3